# Incompatible union types

Tags: typescript

I have these union types:

```
type Role = 'x' | 'y' | 'z' | 't'
type Entity = { personId: string } | { organizationId: string }
type RoleEntity = { role: 'x', personId: string } | { role: 'y', personId: string } | { role: 'z', organizationId: string } | { role: 'y', organizationId: string }
```

and this function that inserts a RoleEntity into an array when passing a role and an entity

```
function laFunc(r: Role, entity: Entity) {

  const nard: RoleEntity[] = []
  switch (r) {
    case 'x':
    case 'y': {
      if ('personId' in entity) {
        nard.push({
          role: r,
          personId: entity.personId
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Argument of type '{ role: "x" | "y"; personId: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RoleEntity'.
  Type '{ role: "x" | "y"; personId: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ role: "y"; personId: string; }'.
    Types of property 'role' are incompatible.
      Type '"x" | "y"' is not assignable to type '"y"'.
        Type '"x"' is not assignable to type '"y"'.(2345)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a union on the `role` itself !

```
type RoleEntity = { role: 'x'|'y', personId: string }  | { role: 'z'|'y', organizationId: string }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gG2gXigcgB5qgH3SbPNAL0PWDQChRIoBRAO2AEtQpUBvKSAJwGc4DAJIATAFxQ%20wHswYBzKAF9cULnB5yAhg2bFNLQaIlSZ8pdXDR4SRizacoPRBAmY0ONAQA03CP0PiktKyCsoqXE5IrqQe3lDqWjp6BsKBJiHmlABmAK4MAMYpUAiaAGJ5%20QAUPBLWED4QTKwgErbNAJSqlJRQUPmCUlAMmjyBdW2gANoAuuxQMz2SAO6s%20QAWUNWdHIu9%20Zp80G5iu30HRwQSO703UMxZm2i8AqnYslCNdiDbp7fDowA6MA5PhrSrXW6QyIuRxeX6Q54BCSfZpAvwvUTw3qKdrwxSnfHYyiKIA)